# update connect by level please check where i am doing wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have a table of Rand_No where i want to update like this

```
UPDATE 
   RAND_NO 
SET 
rand_no1 = select floor(dbms_random.value(30, 35)) result
  from dual
  connect by level <= 366
/
```

I want to enter data between (30, 35) random and till the 366 entries
it worked like this when just insert it

```
insert into rand_no (RAND_NO1)
  select round(dbms_random.value(30, 35)) result
  from dual
  connect by level <= 366
;
```

but not in update i know doing wrong please correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update statement will get:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

If you want to update a column value from a subquery then you have to enclose that in parentheses:

```
UPDATE 
   RAND_NO 
SET 
rand_no1 = (select floor(dbms_random.value(30, 35)) result
  from dual
  connect by level <= 366)
/
```

But as that subquery returns 366 rows that will get

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

You can't set the value *in each row* to all 366 new random numbers, which is that that is attempting to do.

If you want to update every existing row to a new random value then you can just do:

```
update rand_no
set rand_no1 = floor(dbms_random.value(30, 35));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=46ac8b91aaeaf052fe799300732a0768)